# Error: No data exists for the row/column

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I get the following error: `No data exists for the row/column`.

It should retrieve the image

```
sSql = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Attendance ORDER BY Attendance_id DESC"
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(sSql, con)
        Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

        dr.Read()
        lab1id.Text = dr.GetValue(1).ToString
        lab1fname.Text = dr.GetValue(2).ToString
        lab1lname.Text = dr.GetValue(3).ToString
        lab1position.Text = dr.GetValue(4).ToString
        lab1subject.Text = dr.GetValue(5).ToString

        dr.Close()

        sSql = "select Pfile from Faculty where StId = '" & lab1id.Text & "'"
        Dim pcmd As New OleDbCommand(sSql, con)
        Dim pdr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        pdr.Read()
        Dim bits As Byte() = CType(dr("Pfile"), Byte())
        Dim memo As New MemoryStream(bits)
        Dim myimg As New Bitmap(memo)
        imgRetrieve.Image = myimg
        pdr.Close()
```

Comment: On what line do you get the error?

Answer (score 1):

The dr.GetValue(N) is zero-based ordinal. Change your indices:

```
While dr.Read()
    lab1id.Text = dr.GetValue(0).ToString
    lab1fname.Text = dr.GetValue(1).ToString
    lab1lname.Text = dr.GetValue(2).ToString
    lab1position.Text = dr.GetValue(3).ToString
    lab1subject.Text = dr.GetValue(4).ToString
End While

While pdr.Read() '             | you got a typo here. Change `dr` to `pdr`.
    Dim bits As Byte() = CType(pdr("Pfile"), Byte())
    Dim memo As New MemoryStream(bits)
    Dim myimg As New Bitmap(memo)
    imgRetrieve.Image = myimg
End While
```

Consider changing your code to something like this:

```
Using command As OleDbCommand = con.CreateCommand()
    command.CommandText = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Attendance ORDER BY Attendance_id DESC;"
    Using reader As OleDbDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
        While reader.Read()
            lab1id.Text = reader.Item("id").ToString
            lab1fname.Text = reader.Item("fname").ToString
            lab1lname.Text = reader.Item("lname").ToString
            lab1position.Text = reader.Item("position").ToString
            lab1subject.Text = reader.Item("subject").ToString
        End While
    End Using
End Using

Using command As OleDbCommand = con.CreateCommand()
    command.CommandText = "select Pfile from Faculty where StId = @StId;"
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StId", lab1id.Text)
    Using reader As OleDbDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
        While reader.Read()
            Dim bits As Byte() = CType(reader.Item("Pfile"), Byte())
            Using stream As New MemoryStream(bits)
                imgRetrieve.Image = Bitmap.FromStream(stream)
            End Using
        End While
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: ahm.. the data already shows but image cannot retrieve , same error appears.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you never execute `pcmd`, see the following two lines:

```
Dim pcmd As New OleDbCommand(sSql, con)
Dim pdr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader() ' cmd should be replaced with pcmd
```

I would suggest adding [While...End While Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zh1f56zs.aspx) when getting the values from `dr` and `pdr`. You also need to parameterize the second query to avoid [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

```
sSql = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Attendance ORDER BY Attendance_id DESC"
Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(sSql, con)
Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

While dr.Read()
    lab1id.Text = dr.GetValue(1).ToString
    lab1fname.Text = dr.GetValue(2).ToString
    lab1lname.Text = dr.GetValue(3).ToString
    lab1position.Text = dr.GetValue(4).ToString
    lab1subject.Text = dr.GetValue(5).ToString
End While

dr.Close()

sSql = "select Pfile from Faculty where StId = @StId"
Dim pcmd As New OleDbCommand(sSql, con)
pcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StId", lab1id.Text)

Dim pdr As OleDbDataReader = pcmd.ExecuteReader()

While pdr.Read()
    Dim bits As Byte() = CType(dr("Pfile"), Byte())
    Dim memo As New MemoryStream(bits)
    Dim myimg As New Bitmap(memo)
    imgRetrieve.Image = myimg
End While

pdr.Close()
```

Comment: ahm.. the data already shows but image cannot retrieve , same error appears.

Comment: What's the type of `Pfile` column?

Comment: Pfile is OLE object... what should I do?