# How to get a result from the SQL SELECT statement with the use of OleDbDataReader object?

Tags: vb.net, ado.net

I am trying to retrieve a record from my database table with this code:

```
 Dim getParentID = "SELECT Parent_ID FROM ParentandGuardian WHERE First_Name = @fname AND Middle_Name = @mname AND Last_Name = @lname"
 comm = New OleDbCommand(getParentID, MyConn)

 comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", txtPGFirstName.Text)
 comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mname", txtPGMiddleName.Text)
 comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lname", txtPGLastName.Text)

 Reader = comm.ExecuteReader

 MsgBox(Reader.GetValue(0))
```

I get this error that points out to the `MsgBox(Reader.Getvalue(0))` statement:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: No data exists for the row/column.

I'm pretty sure that the query should have at least one result. I have checked the specific database table that the query is pointing to and the values are there. I just can't figure why I keep getting this error. I'm pretty new to VB.NET. Please bear with me.

Comment: First: don't use .AddWithValue. Second: before you can access the fields, you will have to do a Reader.Read()

Comment: @muffi Thank you, sir! I've finally got it! It's a great help for me. I have one more question though. Why did you say, don't use .AddWithValue? This might help me with my future struggles with VB.NET. TIA.

Comment: Because .AddWithValue sometimes guesses the wrong field type. It is always better to add a parameter like `.Add("@param", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = 0`

Answer (score 0):

*"No data exists for the row/column"* indicates what you're missing from the query execution is usage of [`OleDbDataReader.Read()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader.read(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) method. The method used with [`While...End While`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zh1f56zs.aspx) block as given below:

```
Dim message As String
Using MyConn As OleDbConnection(connectionString)

    MyConn.Open()
    Dim getParentID As String = "SELECT Parent_ID FROM ParentandGuardian WHERE First_Name = @fname AND Middle_Name = @mname AND Last_Name = @lname"
    Using comm As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(getParentID, MyConn)
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", txtPGFirstName.Text)
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mname", txtPGMiddleName.Text)
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lname", txtPGLastName.Text)

        Using reader As OleDbDataReader = comm.ExecuteReader()

           While reader.Read()
               message = reader.GetValue(0).ToString()
           End While

           MsgBox(message)
        End Using
    End Using

    MyConn.Close()
End Using
```

The `Read` method used to advance data reader to the first record (or next record for multiple records) before retrieving data from respective row(s).

NB: `OleDbCommand.Parameters.Add` is more preferred over `OleDbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue` since it can declare custom data type(s) to match with each column data type(s) used in database (depending database you're using).

Similar issues:

[Error: No data exists for the row/column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21511171/error-no-data-exists-for-the-row-column)

[Why do I get "No data exists for the row/column" error when I do have data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27722734/why-do-i-get-no-data-exists-for-the-row-column-error-when-i-do-have-data)